# AngularJS directive with dynamic controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a angularJS directive, and i need to do some function from a controller, but i need to get the controller dynamic, for example.

In html A.html i use the directive

The directive template code is:

```
template: '<div class="input-group autocomplete-holder"><form ng-submit="submit()">[...]</div>'
```

The submit() method exists in this html controller, now, i send the controller to directive this:

```
define(['angular', 'admin/AdminStockWarehouseController'], function (angular, AdminStockWarehouseController) {
    'use strict';
```

Now, i need to send other controller, with same function name, then, this will fails, then my question is:

There is any way to get the current controller in a directive to use the submit function thats correspondant or send the function to do in form submit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&` in the definition of the scope of your directive to pass in functions

```
module.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
           submit: '&'
        }
    };
});
```

the function will become accessible through your directive's scope, so the template of the directive would look like you described it:

```
<div class="input-group autocomplete-holder"><form ng-submit="submit()">[...]</div>'
```

And you would use the directive like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <div my-directive submit="submitFunctionOne"></div>
   <div my-directive submit="submitFunctionTwo"></div>
</div>
```

where these functions are defined in the controller:

```
module.controller('MyController', function() {
  $scope.submitFunctionOne = function() {...};
  $scope.submitFunctionTwo = function() {...};
});
```

[Here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding) is a great video tutorial explaining how this is done.